# R- tapply doesn't keep dates formated

Tags: r, function, date, tapply

I need to do a fast aggregation by id_client of dates: min, max, difference of dates in months and quantity of months.

Example table:

```
tbl<-data.frame(id_cliente=c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3), 
fecha=c('2013-01-01', '2013-06-01','2013-05-01', '2013-04-01', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-01','2013-05-01','2013-04-01'))
```

Format dates:

```
tbl$fecha<-as.Date(as.character(tbl$fecha))
```

My first approach was ddply:

```
tbl2<-ddply(tbl, .(id_cliente), summarize, cant=length(id_cliente), 
max=max(fecha), min=min(fecha),
dif=length(seq(from=min, to=max, by='month')))
```

I got the desired result, but with my real table takes too much time.
So I tried tapply:

```
tbl3<-data.frame(cbind(dif=tapply(tbl$fecha, list(tbl$id_cliente), secuencia),
        hay=tapply(tbl$fecha, list(tbl$id_cliente), length),
        min=tapply(tbl$fecha, list(tbl$id_cliente), min),
        max=tapply(tbl$fecha, list(tbl$id_cliente), max)
        ))
```

The result was:

```
> tbl3
  dif hay   min   max
   6   4 15706 15857
   1   1 15706 15706
   5   3 15706 15826
```

In this case I got instead of dates, numbers. So since the following works, I tried using as.Date inside tapply:

```
as.Date(15706, origin='1970-01-01')

MIN<-function(x){as.Date(min(x), origin='1970-01-01')}
```

The function works but with tapply doesn't.

```
tbl3<-data.frame(cbind(min=tapply(tbl$fecha, list(tbl$id_cliente), MIN)))
```

And I still got the number instead of date.
How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `base R`, the `?Date` class is converted to the number of days from Jan. 1, 1970. Try using `dplyr` or `data.table` to preserve the date class:

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>% group_by(id_cliente) %>%
        summarise(dif=length(seq(min(fecha), max(fecha), by='month')),
                  hay=length(fecha),
                  min=min(fecha),
                  max=max(fecha))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
# 
#   id_cliente dif hay        min        max
# 1          1   6   4 2013-01-01 2013-06-01
# 2          2   1   1 2013-01-01 2013-01-01
# 3          3   5   3 2013-01-01 2013-05-01
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tbl)[,.(dif=length(seq(min(fecha), max(fecha), by='month')),
              hay= .N,
              min=min(fecha),
              max=max(fecha)), by=id_cliente]
#    id_cliente dif hay        min        max
# 1:          1   6   4 2013-01-01 2013-06-01
# 2:          2   1   1 2013-01-01 2013-01-01
# 3:          3   5   3 2013-01-01 2013-05-01
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late, but I figured I would put this here for the people still googling this issue.

Interestingly, `tapply` returns the correct results when you keep the date column in text format and then you can convert to a date after:

```
tbl<-data.frame(id_cliente=c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3), 
                fecha=c('2013-01-01', '2013-06-01','2013-05-01', '2013-04-01', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-01','2013-05-01','2013-04-01'))
tbl3<-data.frame(cbind(dif=tapply(tbl$fecha, list(tbl$id_cliente), seq),
                        hay=tapply(tbl$fecha, list(tbl$id_cliente), length),
                        min=tapply(tbl$fecha, list(tbl$id_cliente), min),
                        max=tapply(tbl$fecha, list(tbl$id_cliente), max))) 
head(tbl3)
#         dif hay        min        max
# 1, 2, 3, 4   4 2013-01-01 2013-06-01
#          1   1 2013-01-01 2013-01-01
#    1, 2, 3   3 2013-01-01 2013-05-01
```